# Equal products involving unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

$$u^T xu  = u^Tu x$$

where $u$ is unit vector, and $x$ is a vector.

How do I see this is true?

Both $u, x$ live in $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: This is undefined. $\boldsymbol u, \boldsymbol x$ cannot be multiplied together. Their size do not admit multiplication.

Comment: @xbh : I would take $u^T x$ to be a product of matrices, and its value is a $1\times1$ matrix, thus a scalar, and then multiplying it by the succeeding $u$ is multiplying a vector $u$ by the preceeding scalar. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh thank you for clarification. I totally missed this explanation.

Comment: To be consistent with matrix multiplication, this would be better written with the scalars on the right side, vectors on the left: $uu^Tx = xu^Tu$

Answer (score 2):

It's not true, in general. It's only true if $x$ is parallel to $u$.

$u$ being a unit vector means that $u^Tu=1$, so the right side of your equation is just $x$. But the left side is the projection of $x$ parallel to $u$.

Example:

$$u = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\quad x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$u^Tu = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0\cdot0+1\cdot1 = 1$$

$$u^Tx = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = 0\cdot x_1+1\cdot x_2 = x_2$$

$$u^Txu = x_2u = x_2\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$